# Bring other running app's window to front

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

What I am trying to achieve: when user presses "buy" in my app, App Store window should appear with my app url in it.

This works fine when App Store is **not running**: `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"macappstore://..."]];`

But when App Store is **already running** and is **minimised** in the dock it's window doesn't show up. It becomes active, yes, but the window doesn't appear.

What I have already tried: fetched app using `NSRunningApplication` and trying to `unhide`, `activateWithOptions:` it, but this doesn't work.

I don't see more options in `NSWorkspace` and `NSRunningApplication`, so if someone have some solutions for this, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Mmm I can't think of any approach that does not involve Applescript or Accessibility APIs which then requires the user give your app access permission which is even worse. (I mean, you could quit and relaunch App Store, but that's jarring.) Honestly this is bad behavior in App Store, so you should file a report with Apple noting the window doesn't come to the front. It won't help you now, though.

Comment: I will certainly fill report, but maybe someone has some workaround here.

Comment: I have filled report for Apple, regarding how Mac App Store behaves, I will update you guys if they will respond.

Answer (score 1):

But doesn't this bring it to the front even if it's minimized?

```
NSWorkspace.shared.launchApplication("App Store")
```

Comment: This solution worked for me on macOS 11. Previously I was using `activateWithOptions(pid: 123, options: NSApplication.ActivationOptions.activateIgnoringOtherApps)`, however in BigSur this was bringing all of the application windows to the foreground, wheras using `launchApplication` brings the app to the foreground and maintains window layering.